# Views Bulk Operations skip confirmation

Tags: 7, views

I have defined a custom action for a VBO.

```
function expense_action_info() {
  return [
    'expense_finalize_action' => [
      'type' => 'node',
      'label' => t('Approve and finalize expense'),
      'behavior' => ['changes_property'],
      'configurable' => TRUE,
      'vbo_configurable' => FALSE,
      'aggregate' => FALSE,
    ],
  ];
}
```

I've also created a configuration form for this action and rendered it along with the view.

```
function expense_finalize_action_form($settings, &$form_state) {
  $form['kickback_note'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => 'new'
  ];
  return $form;
}

function expense_finalize_action_submit($form, $form_state) {
  return ['kickback_note' => $form_state['values']['kickback_note']];
}
```

When I submit the VBO I've redirected to page of this custom form and I need to click on the Next button to proceed the action. 
As I have provided required values in the form I need to skip this step. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your view, under your field configuration, at "select bulk operation" section under the action there should be a "Skip confirmation step" option; uncheck it and you're ready to go